# Path XX contains invalid priority: Must be a String, Double, ServerValue, or Null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm trying to set a value to a child using the server ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.

```
    val userRef = database.reference.child(userId).child("cache")
    val beerRef = userRef.child("beers")
    beerRef.child(beer.id).setValue(beer)
    val beerExpiration = userRef.child("expiration/beer")
    val serverTimeStamp = mapOf(Pair("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP))
    beerExpiration.child(beer.id).setValue("timestamp", serverTimeStamp)
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Path '/xxxxxxxx/cache/expiration/beer/4010' contains invalid priority: Must be a string, double, ServerValue, or null
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
    at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:67)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
    at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining serverTimeStamp as a map with

```
val serverTimeStamp = mapOf(Pair("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP))
```

Then you're trying to set the value of timestamp in your server to this map with

```
beerExpiration.child(beer.id).setValue("timestamp", serverTimeStamp)
```

instead of setting it to the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

I presume your issue will be fixed with (not tested)

```
beerExpiration.child(beer.id).setValue("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: hmm it really seems a mistake. I will test it

Comment: @alexpfx Has your issue been solved? If so, please accept one of the answers. If not, please give an update :)

Comment: I don't fix the problem yet, doing the form you have suggest it saves (<beerId>)/"timestamp" (as plain String). It doesn't convert the value correctly. I was only able to solve this using java api (Collections.singletonMap).  Don't sure how to make it work with pure kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is already a `Map<String, String>`. In effect, you are trying to send a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` to Firebase, which it is not happy about.

You might just want to get rid of `val serverTimeStamp = mapOf(Pair("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP))` and just pass `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to setValue.

As a small aside, the way you're constructing your Map might be shorter and more Kotlinesque if you use the `a to b` notation which creates a pair for you, as in `mapOf("thing" to "foo")`.

Comment: In fact the correct form is Map<String, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP> but I couldn't do it using kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using:

```
val map = hashMapOf("timestamp" to ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
ref.child(id).setValue(map)
```

or similar java api code:

```
val map = Collections.singletonMap("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
        ref.child(id).setValue("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
```

and it works.

---

When I try the code below, as suggest in both others answers:

```
ref.child(id).setValue("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
```

It persists "timestamp" as literal:

[image]

In fact the correct way to store server value is to pass a map to setValue, like this example from [here][2]:

```
HashMap<String, Object> updatedTimeStamp = new HashMap<>();
    updatedTimeStamp.put(Constants.FIREBASE_PROPERTY_TIMESTAMP, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```